# How do you run ShellScript on Windows?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm just a student and I'm learning ShellScript in my college. In college lab, our ma'am just asked to enter an IP address in PUTTY and launch it, open Vi editor and do programming. How do I do it at home? I run XP on my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you install [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) at home.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), install it on you host with relevant utilites and try it.

Comment: I missed the earlier post in matter of seconds I suppose :)

Answer (score 1):

Would running a version of Linux from a DVD do the trick for you?

You can download a disk image of Knoppix Linux from their web site http://www.knoppix.net/

and burn it to a DVD. You can then reboot the computer and run Knoppix from the DVD without changing anything on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd hate to pass judgement on a course I'm not taking, but it sounds like you might not get the entire story about shell scripting, based on your description.

As others have suggested, Cygwin is the way to go, it's excellent.  Here's a nice [how-to](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) for bash.  I'd avoid tcsh or any other version of the c shell (there be monsters).

If you end up needing to do something more advanced, bash can be cumbersome.  You should consider a general purpose language, such as [python](http://python.org), which is also available in cygwin, or as a stand-alone windows installer.  For process control, though, bash is king.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use Xemacs for window and respective windows packages.

Answer (score 0):

However i feel Cygwin is the most appropriate solution. You can also go with MKSTool Kit but this toolkit is not free.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using putty on your own computer and using the ip address she gave you? Depending on how the network is set up you might be able to use it that way. Cygwin is good but if you need to do Linux specific stuff look at [Wubi](http://wubi-installer.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Cygwin on your home computer. It is a port of many Unix tools to windows, so you can work in unix-style on your windows computer.

Or you can connect to the school computer from home using Putty just like you did it at school (provided that the computer is accessible from the outside). Then you'll have the same environment accessible from home, including the files you work on.