# How to run .sh files in Windows?

Tags: unix, dojo, sh

I download some repositories of DojoToolkit in GitHub that have .sh files, I know .sh extension are typically shell scripts written in Unix, but exist a way to run this in Windows?

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477371/how-do-you-run-shellscript-on-windows helps

Comment: I'm curious what sh files you are referring to; the build script has both a .sh and a .bat version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cygwin is probably the easiest way.

http://www.cygwin.com/

Alternatively if you're already using git-bash for github etc you can use it to run .sh scripts too.

Answer (score 0):

Porting unix stuff to windows is sometime possible (mostly thanks to cygwin, as pointed out by other answers) but except for simple stuff, you'll quickly enter into a compatibility hell, never knowing what goes wrong.

I recommend **setting up a virtual machine running a simple ubuntu server**.

That what I use daily. VMware server is free, ubuntu installs perfectly on it. Shell via ssh and file share via a samba server on the linux VM. File editor on windows.

Works perfectly, no more compatibility problems.